# retrieve post slug by post_tags taxonomy

Tags: posts, taxonomy, tags, slug

My scenario:
I have a part of a site which retrieves all post_tags terms for a specific category

the code:

```
                query_posts('category_name='. $category[0]->cat_name);
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $posttags = get_the_tags();
                    if ($posttags) {
                        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                            $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> name; 
                        }
                    }
                endwhile; endif; 


                $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags_arr); 

                foreach ($tags_arr as $cat_by_tag) {
                    $output_promotion .= '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url'). '/' . $category[0]->cat_name . '/' . ????? . '/">'. $cat_by_tag .'</a></li>';
                }

                echo $output_promotion;
```

This all works fine, the code retrieves all post_tags and removes duplicates. I'm stuck now with the post slug. What I want is: retrieve post slug by post_tag term.

Example:

Post title: ABC Post

post slug: abc-post

Tag in that post: ABC Tag

I need something like this:

```
<a href="http://site/abc-post">ABC Tag</a>
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure but try this:

```
query_posts('category_name='. $category[0]->cat_name);
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $posttags = get_the_tags();
                    if ($posttags) {
                        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                            $all_tags_arr[] = array($tag->name,wp_basename(get_permalink())); 
                        }
                    }

                endwhile; endif; 

                foreach ($all_tags_arr as $cat_by_tag) {
                    $output_promotion .= '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url'). '/' . $cat_by_tag[1] . '/">'. $cat_by_tag[0] .'</a></li>';
                }

                print_r($output_promotion);
```